# Looping through SQL Server records

Tags: c#, sql-server

I'm coming from a data background, and I am completely new to C#. But I want to learn something and try to have some `.sql` files generated by the content of a SQL Server database. I'm trying a whole day now and I am really close to what I need I guess. I now have the code that is listed below.

When I enable:

```
System.Data.DataTable schema = conn.GetSchema("TABLES");
```

Everything works and it gives me the whole list of schema's. But I don't want to loop through the schema's, I want to loop through the records that the query that is listed below that line provides.

Can somebody help this C# n00b with a solution or hint? What I want is a way to not loop through the schema's, but through the output of my query. I've tried command.rows, ad.rows and ds.rows. But that's not good. Is there a way to put the query output into a var so that I can loop through it?

```
<#@ template language="C#" debug="True" hostspecific="True" #>
<#@ output extension=".sql" #>
<#@ assembly name="System.Data" #>

<#@ assembly name="System.xml" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Collections.Generic" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Data.SqlClient" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Data" #>
    
        <#
            string connectionString = "myconnectionstring"; 
            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString); 
            conn.Open(); 
            //System.Data.DataTable schema = conn.GetSchema("TABLES"); 
            string selectQuery = "select * from [config].[SourcesAndObjects]"; 
            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(selectQuery,conn); 
            SqlDataAdapter ad = new SqlDataAdapter(command); 
            System.Data.DataSet ds = new DataSet(); 
            
            foreach(System.Data.DataRow row in schema.Rows) 
            {                
            #>             
            CREATE TABLE <#= row["TABLE_NAME"].ToString().Trim('s') #>                            
            {
                <#                 
                    command.CommandText = selectQuery.ToString(); 
                    ad.FillSchema(ds, SchemaType.Mapped, row["TABLE_NAME"].ToString());

                    foreach (DataColumn dc in ds.Tables[0].Columns)
                    {
                        #>
                    
                    [<#= dc.ColumnName #>] AS <#= dc.DataType.Name #>
                    {
                        [<#= dc.ColumnName.Replace(dc.ColumnName[0].ToString(), dc.ColumnName[0].ToString()) #>],
                    }                    
                <#    }                 #>
            }                
            <#    
            }  #>    
}
```

Comment: Where exactly are you stuck? Asking for hints is too broad.

Comment: I get stuck at that the foreach loop loops through the schema variable that is filled with: 

conn.GetSchema("TABLES");

I want to loop through a variable which holds the output of the query... But I have a select query which is executed I guess, but I've tried to loop throug command.Rows or ad.Rows or ds.Rows, but that gave me errors that indicated that that is not possible. So I hope to hear how to create a var with the results of the query so that I can loop through it.

Comment: Please [edit] the question so that viewers don't have to sift through comments to find all the relevant information. While you're at it, expand on the description. You understand what you mean but none of us have been in your head (I assume).

Comment: Have a read through the [SqlDataAdapter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.data.sqlclient.sqldataadapter) class documentation. Perhaps you'll want to invoke `ad.Fill(ds)` to retrieve your result sets instead of `ad.FillSchema(ds)` to retrieve the schemata?

Comment: Thank you @AlwaysLearning. That was really what I needed. I now have it working!